# \$V_{BE}\$ increasing from saturation to active mode of BJT with \$I_{B}\$ constant

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, bjt

Consider the configuration of common emitter BJT
[image]

Suppose that \$I_B\$ is held constant (regulating \$V_{BB}\$) and \$V_{CE}\$ is increased from \$0V\$ (regulating \$V_{CC}\$), while \$V_{BE}\$ is measured.

When I tried this measurement I noticed that passing from saturation mode \$V_{CE}<0.2 V\$ to active mode \$V_{CE}>0.2 V\$ (increasing \$V_{CE}\$) \$V_{BE}\$  increased rapidly.

How can this be explained? I mean, the value of \$V_{CE}\$ does not influence the value of \$V_{BE}\$ necessary to have the same \$I_B\$, does it?

Comment: "Ib is held constant (regulating Vbb)" is it? Try putting an ammeter in series with Rb while you change Vcc

Comment: @JImDearden That's what I did and I observed \$I_{B}\$ almost constant (slightly increasing, Early effect) for \$V_{CE}>0.2\$ but when I passed from saturation to active \$I_{B}\$ decreased and for this reason it was necessary to increase \$V_{BB}\$ (and hence \$V_{BE}\$ to get \$I_{B}\$ back). I must say that \$R_{B}\$ was like \$10k \Omega\$ (quite high) if you are referring to possible damages due to high currents, otherwise I do not understand what you are referring to..

Comment: At low Vce the base-collector (parallel to base-emitter) is forward biased so it takes extra current even if Vbb is constant.

Answer (score 2):

The collector-base junction is in parallel with the base-emitter junction and is forward-biased when the collector is at less than Vbe.

As it turns out the voltage drop of the collector-base junction is typically **somewhat less** than that of the emitter-base junction for the same current as well, so having the collector voltage at 0V means that some of the base current flows out of the collector to ground, so Vbe is less than with the collector open. This is a consequence of the asymmetry in the construction of most modern transistors.

Above maybe 100mV there should be little change in Vbe regardless of Vce (before breakdown).

If you run the below simulation, you will find that more than 95% of the base current flows out through the collector, reducing the Vbe by maybe 5-10mV.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVsd09.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If your test bench is set up like the attached schematic, then IB is *not* held constant.

When the transistor is in saturation, there is substantial base current so you get a drop over RB. As you pass into the active region, IB falls to IC divided by beta, the drop over RB decreases, and VBE increases as a result.